# Multiple pagers on same view page

Tags: 7, views

When creating a view whose display type is page, we got an option to apply pagination using pager option given in view, where you get sort of radio buttons to select pager, full, mini, etc..

Do we have check-boxes instead of those radio buttons?

What If want to render 2 different pagers in my view display - full and mini?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `Expose items per page` option under Pager options, so this might help a bit. This allows users to change how many results they want to see per page.

Why do you want to show different pagers for the same set of results? Pagers can add to the performance strain.

There are some contributed modules that add to the Views pager, try searching for them and see if they come close to what you need. For example [Pagerer](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagerer) or [Views Extra Pagers](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_extra_pagers).

Comment: I have a calendar sort of listing. One pager gives functionality such as click on next will give data of next year and another pager to view sets of results for a particular year itself, lets say 156th page of 1997 year. Any recommendation or alternative approach is welcome.

Comment: I would create the Filter for the year, and Expose it, so users can choose which year should show in the results. That way the Pager will page through only the chosen year. You can override the Title with tokens to reflect which filter the user has set.